# ' TypeError: [Variable].getDay is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx

I need a time differnce in my react componenet. I have used MobX for my state management.Some Part of the code:

```
  <Icon name='clock' /> Expiry Date :- {format(books.returnDate, 'eeee do MMMM')}
  <Icon name='hourglass start' />Remaining Time:- {timeDiff(books.returnDate)}
```

In the above code books.returnDate is bind successfully. Now I need the time difference between `books.returnDate` and current Date so I called a function timeDiff

```
const timeDiff = (t2: Date) => {

        const t1 = new Date();
        console.log(t1.getDay())

        var d2 = t2.getDay();
        var d1 = t1.getDay();

        return (d2 - d1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000);
    }
```

In timeDiff function the values of both dates are:-

[image]

but the difference is not calculated. I am getting an error:

> [mobx] Encountered an uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[observer(LibrarianManager)]' TypeError: t2.getDay is not a function

How Can I find this differece in days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off the assumption that `books.returnDate` is coming from your backend, probably as a part of a JSON response.  You probably just forgot to convert it from a string to a date, since JSON can't store an actual date object.

So when you do something like:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('/api/books');
setState({books: data.books});
```

you just need to do:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('/api/books');
setState({books: data.books.map((book) => {
    book.returnDate = new Date(book.returnDate);
})});
```

or you could just do:

```
const timeDiff = (t2: Date) => {
    if (!(t2 instanceof Date)) t2 = new Date(t2);
    const t1 = new Date();
    console.log(t1.getDay)

    var d2 = t2.getDay();
    var d1 = t1.getDay();

    return (d2 - d1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried last step It worked!!!!!!!!! xD

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getDay` wrongly. It should be `console.log(t1.getDay())`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already using `date-fns` or some similar library. If so then you don't need to invent things by yourself, just use appropriate function from the library, for example:

```
import differenceInHours from 'date-fns/differenceInHours'

differenceInHours(dateLeft, dateRight)
```

More: https://date-fns.org/docs/differenceInHours

Please note that date-fns v2 expects `Date` or `number` as an input anyway, not string.